# Bad Request 400 while accessing WCF Rest service (WebGet)

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I have built a WCF REST web service on visual studio 2008 (on windows xp)

When I try to access the webservice through the URL it returns 400 bad request error.

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "hello/{Name}")]
[OperationContract]
string SayHello(string Name);
```

Please help.

**web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DNNServiceBehavior" name="DNNService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IDNNService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior" contract="IDNNService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DNNServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```