# WebGet method gives error 400 "Bad Request" in WCF REST Service Application

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bad Request 400 while accessing WCF Rest service (WebGet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725784/bad-request-400-while-accessing-wcf-rest-service-webget)

Hi All,

Let me explain what I am doing with WCF rest service. Here's my code and config:

1. **IDNNService interface**

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IDNNService
   {
       [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "hello/{Name}")]
       [OperationContract]
       string SayHello(string Name);
   }
   ```
2. **Service class** that implements the interface

   ```
   public class DNNService : IDNNService
   {
       public string SayHello(string Name)
       {
           return string.Format("Hello {0}", Name);
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Configuration** file

   ```
   <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
         <service behaviorConfiguration="DNNServiceBehavior" name="DNNService">
            <endpoint 
                   address="" 
                   binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                   contract="IDNNService">
               <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost" />
               </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint 
                   address="mex" 
                   binding="mexHttpBinding"  
                   contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <endpoint 
                   address="rest" 
                   binding="webHttpBinding" 
                   behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior" 
                   contract="IDNNService"/>
         </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DNNServiceBehavior">
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
             <behavior name="httpBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
             </behavior>
         </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
   </system.serviceModel>
   ```

I am able to generate my SVC file that return correct information with wsdl

But the problem is when i try to access my actual method

```
http://localhost/DC560X_rest/DesktopModules/DNNCentric-RestService/Entities/DNNService.svc/rest/hello/prabhakar
```

1. IE Dispaly "400 Bad Request"
2. Firefox Display Blank Page

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have in your uri template two '}' ?

Comment: Can you also show your hosting code and configuration and url used to call the service?

Comment: If you just access DNNService.svc do you see web service information page with link to WSDL?

Comment: Yes service info are there with link to WSDL

Comment: How did you call the service - what URL did you use?

Comment: Why did you create second question instead of adding information to your first one?

Comment: I have just used your code and it works ...

Comment: Sorry for creating Duplicate question

Comment: Can u please let me know , How it's work on your machine,I am using IIS 6 With XP, Is it IIS 6 Issue or something else

Comment: Let me know your OS name And IIS Version

Comment: IIS 6 is not available on WinXP!

Comment: Can u please explain where i am wrong ? why it's not working in my machine

Comment: Questions have been merged, please don't close as dupe.  @user you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4732781/edit) your question to add detail at any time, and comment on answers if you need more information.

Comment: Problem solve, it's working fine with iis7 and above ... Thank u all

Answer (score 2):

Your URL looks nutty as squirrel etc.

Set a URL for the service

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DNNServiceBehavior" name="DNNService">
         <endpoint 
                address="http://*:12345/Derp" 
                binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                contract="IDNNService">
            <identity>
```

(you may or may not have to ensure port 12345 is unblocked by your firewall)

then use the url:  `http://localhost:12345/Derp` (of course, from the same machine it is installed on) to test your service.